# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext') while using useMutation and apollo server for graphQL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, apollo

I am using useMutation to create a username on login using graphQL and apollo server with nextJS, however my page is not rendering. The backend request for creating the username in graphQL playground works and I am also able to log it in my nextJS app.

Below is my login page

auth.tsx

```
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { Session } from "next-auth";
import { Center, Stack, Text, Button, Image, Input } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserOperations from "../../graphql/operations/user";

interface IAuthProps {
  session: Session | null;
  reloadSession: () => void;
}

interface CreateUsernameData {
  createUsername: {
    success: boolean;
    error: string;
  };
}

interface CreateUsernameVariables {
  username: string;
}

const Auth: React.FunctionComponent<IAuthProps> = ({
  session,
  reloadSession,
}) => {
  console.log("session: ", session);

  const [username, setUsername] = useState("default");
  const [createUsername, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation<
    CreateUsernameData,
    CreateUsernameVariables
  >(UserOperations.Mutations.createUsername);

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    if (!username) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await createUsername({ variables: { username } });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("onSubmit error", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Center height="100vh">
      <Stack align={"center"}>
        {session ? (
          <>
            <Text fontSize={"3xl"}>Create Username</Text>
            <Input
              placeholder="Enter a username"
              value={username}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setUsername(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
            <Button width="100%" onClick={onSubmit}>
              Save
            </Button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Text fontSize="3xl">MessengerQL</Text>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                signIn("google");
              }}
              leftIcon={<Image height="20px" src="/images/googlelogo.png" />}
            >
              Continue with google
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
      </Stack>
    </Center>
  );
};

export default Auth;
```

_app.tsx

```
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { theme } from "../chakra/theme";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "../graphql/apollo-client";

function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ChakraProvider>
      </SessionProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { theme } from "../chakra/theme";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { client } from "../graphql/apollo-client";

function App({ Component, pageProps: { session, ...pageProps } }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <SessionProvider session={session}>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ChakraProvider>
      </SessionProvider>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

user.ts

importing the gql string from user.ts

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const UserOperations = {
  Queries: {
    searchUsers: gql`
      query SearchUsers($username: String!) {
        searchUsers(username: $username) {
          id
          username
        }
      } 
    `,
  },
  Mutations: {
    createUsername: gql`
      mutation CreateUsername($username: String!) {
        createUsername(username: $username) {
          success
          error
        }
      }
    `,
  },
  Subscriptions: {},
};

export default UserOperations;
```

Additionally i get a warning

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)

2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks

3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Main error

```
caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at Object.useContext (/Users/adi/Desktop/chat app/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:1618:21)
    at useApolloClient (/Users/adi/Desktop/chat app/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/hooks.cjs:30:27)
    at useMutation (/Users/adi/Desktop/chat app/node_modules/@apollo/client/react/hooks/hooks.cjs:430:18)
    at Auth (webpack-internal:///./src/components/Auth/Auth.tsx:27:118)
    at renderWithHooks (/Users/adi/Desktop/chat app/frontend/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/Users/adi/Desktop/chat app/frontend/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
```

if i comment out

```
const [createUsername, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation<
    CreateUsernameData,
    CreateUsernameVariables
  >(UserOperations.Mutations.createUsername);
```

the login page renders. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong